# Dataflow BigQuery read from ValueProvider: 'StaticValueProvider' object has no attribute 'projectId'

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using the Python SDK for apache beam. Im attempting to read data from BigQuery via a ValueProvider (as the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery) states that these are allowed).

```
def run(bq_source_table: ValueProvider,
        pipeline_options=None):

    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).setup_file = "./setup.py"

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read from BigQuery" >> ReadFromBigQuery(table=bq_source_table)
        )
```

The options are declared as follows:

```
class CPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            "--bq_source_table",
            help="The BigQuery source table name..\n"
                 '"<project>:<dataset>.<table>".'
        )
```

Executing the pipeline yields the error below:

> AttributeError: 'StaticValueProvider' object has no attribute 'projectId' [while running 'Read from BigQuery/Read/SDFBoundedSourceReader/ParDo(SDFBoundedSourceDoFn)/SplitAndSizeRestriction']

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I do **not** want to use Flex Templates.

---

*EDIT*: Good thing to mention is that the `query` param *does* support the `ValueProvider`. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be to use Flex Templates.

Comment: I currently worked around the issue by providing a source query ValueProvider to the BigQuery connector. Still strange that the connector does not accept a ValueProvider for the source table name.